# Expression expected Error when using php variables in ChartJS functions

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I am trying to input my Controller variable in ChartJS Javascript file to Dynamically create charts in ChartJS

> Expression Expected at "<?"

Controller.php

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        
        @$result= DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id =?", [$user_id]);

        $result_arr = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

        $label_array = array();
        foreach($result_arr as $d)
        {
            $label_array[]=$d['label_element'];   
        }

        $data_array = array();
        foreach($result_arr as $d)
        {
            $data_array[]=$d['data_element'];   
        }

        return view('home', ['labels'=>$label_array, 'data'=>$data_array]);
    }
```

chart-pie-demo.js:

```
// Pie Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: <?php echo json_encode($labels); ?>, // Error Line
    datasets: [{
      data: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>, // Error Line
      backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
    }],
  },
```

Comment: Since `chart-pie-demo.js` is a `.js` file, you can't use `<?php ... ?>` syntax in it... You can do `<script>let labels = {{ json_encode($labels) }};</script>` inside of `home.blade.php` before you include the `chart-pie-demo.js`, or you'll need to load the data via AJAX.

Comment: It's a `.js` file. I think your http server isn't interpreting it as `.php`

Comment: You could do `chart-pie-demo.js.php` then have a rewrite rule for `chart-pie-demo.js` to map to the PHP version. Make sure you send appropriate headers if you take that approach though... `$labels` and `$data` also wouldn't be in scope here.